# Laravel Backpack select2_from_ajax pass multiple or extra search keyword for search

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

Current select2_from_ajax only pass the search `q` for search term. How can I pass multiple search info to the method?

I need to pass the current record ID /admin/product/4.

I need to sql filter by product_id 4 and keyword. How can I do that?

```
CRUD::field('select2_from_ajax')
                ->type('select2_from_ajax')
                ->label("Article <small class='font-light'>(select2_from_ajax for a 1-n relationship)</small>")
                ->entity('article')
                ->attribute('title')
                ->model('Backpack\NewsCRUD\app\Models\Article')
                ->data_source(url('api/article'))
                ->placeholder('Select an article')
                ->minimum_input_length(2)
                ->wrapper(['class' => 'form-group col-md-6'])
                ->tab('Selects');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to pass all form values just add `->include_all_form_fields(true)`.

The full field definition will be the following:

```
CRUD::field('select2_from_ajax')
                ->type('select2_from_ajax')
                ->label("Article <small class='font-light'>(select2_from_ajax for a 1-n relationship)</small>")
                ->entity('article')
                ->attribute('title')
                ->model('Backpack\NewsCRUD\app\Models\Article')
                ->data_source(url('api/article'))
                ->placeholder('Select an article')
                ->minimum_input_length(2)
                ->wrapper(['class' => 'form-group col-md-6'])
                ->tab('Selects')
                ->include_all_form_fields(true);
```